# Accessing WPDB Multidimensional JSON Array w/ Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am having trouble accessing json values return from an ajax call.

Here is the call:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'user_id=' + user.user_id + '&user_login='+ user.user_login,
    //dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://###/user-stats.php',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        //alert(data.games_won[0]['winner_id']);
        //console.log(data);
        if(data) {
            $('#hand-stats-display').html(data);
            //$.mobile.changePage( "#user-home", { transition: "fade"} );
        }else{ 
            $('.messages').html("No stats available at this time... Please try again later.");
            //alert(data);
        }

    },
    error: function(){
        //console.log(data);
        alert('Ajax Login Request ✗');
    }
    });
```

Here is the PHP:

```
$myrows['hands_won'] = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_winners WHERE user_id=" . $user_id );


if ( $myrows ) 
{
    //echo('Rows Exist ✓');
    //echo "List of {$meta_key1} posts, sorted by {$meta_key2}";
    foreach ( $myrows as $id ) 
    {
        $creds[]=$id;
        //echo('MyRows: ' . $myrows[id]);
    }
}

//echo "Winner ID:" .$myrows[0]->win_id;
//echo "Winner 2 ID:" .$myrows[1]->win_id;



echo json_encode($creds);
```

It returns a json object like:

```
[{"win_id":"1","user_id":"1","game_id":"1"},{"win_id":"2","user_id":"1","game_id":"2"}]
```

I can not seem to access these with the javascript I am using. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to use something like `result = $.parseJSON(data)`.  Then you can access the data with `result.win_id`, for example.

As an aside, you should sanitize the input to that database query using `prepare` with something like:

`$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_winners WHERE user_id=%d", $user_id ) );`

Comment: Still not working for me... It seems like `result.win_id` should be something like `result[0].win_id`, bc it is multidimensional. appreciate your time.

Comment: Yea, you could also use jQuery's `$.each` to loop through them.  When you say it's not working, what does that mean exactly?  Can you try logging the result?

`result = $.parseJSON(data); console.log(result);`

Comment: Ok using `$.each(data, function(i,item){
    var win_id = '<h1>'+item.win_id+'</h1>';
    alert(win_id);

    
   });` I can see that two rows are returned, which is correct.  Unfortunately, the win_id value is still undefined. I just can't figure out the syntax for accessing the variable at this time.

Comment: Isn't the syntax what you just described?  Inside of the `.each` loop you can just call `item.win_id`, and presumable `item.user_id` and `item.game_id` as well.  As for why it's undefined, that is very hard to say without seeing the rest of your code.  Is the $wpdb result undefined?  Are there any errors?  Make sure you enable WP_DEBUG.  If possible, maybe drop the rest of your code into a gist or something to help figure out what else might be the cause.

Comment: Ok, so I fell victim to a few of my own errors and in the end the loop ultimately helped me out. I still can't figure out how to access them outside the loop, but at least I can dump the values out to something I can read. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to access them as you described in your first comment, with something like `result[0].win_id`, but I can't think of a good reason not to use the loop.  If you know which one you want to start with, why get any others?  If you're accessing multiple items directly, for different purposes, it seems like you should probably be querying and returning your data in a different way (obviously I can't say for sure since I don't really know what you're doing with it).